# Which license for ImageResizer with DiskCache?

Tags: imageresizer

One of our clients are using ImageResizer for their EPiServer CMS website.

They are using version 4.0.5 and the following plugins:

- MvcRoutingShim
- EpiseverBlobReaderPlugin
- DiskCache

They only have one domain.

I've been trying to read up on your different licenses but are uncertain which is needed for our client.

Will "Performance" suffice or do we need another license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got reply from ImageResizer support:
"The performance license should work unless there is a load balancer or 
reverse proxy in place which changes the HOST header."